# Click events in body in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a react component which adds a border when clicked. Now I have 3 similar components on the same page. When I click anyone of them,it adds a border. When I click on any of the other remaining components I want the border to be removed from first and added to the second. Also if I click anywhere in the document other than the components, existing border if any must be removed. I have achieved the same using vanilla Js but unable to implement it using react. Any help is appreciated.

```
import React from 'react'

function NavItem() {
    const menu = {
        initial: "noborder",
        final: "border",
      };
      const [itemStyle, setItemStyle] = useState("");
    const handleClick=()=>{
        setItemStyle(final)
    }
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick} className={`${itemStyle}`}>NavItem</div>
  )
}

export default NavItem
```

Comment: The entire point of React is that it doesn't let you wire stuff like that up lazily. You will need to have the border state in a shared parent component and pass it down as props, along with a setter to use as a click handler. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Even then how can I change props based on click on any other part of the document. In vanilla JS you can easily check it using document.addEventlistener but how the same is achieved in react.

Comment: You can attach a listener to document that changes the state in the parent component that owns that state with the `useEffect` hook. In fact, you can use variations of that pattern to completely bypass how React is intended to work. Which is why it isn't more prominently featured in the documentation: you *can* do that but usually you don't need to and it causes more problems than it solves. Whether or not you need that *here* is a call you'll have to make.

Comment: So any other way other than using a listener? I also have similar issue with scroll events.

Comment: React is a *component* model. Any thing that you need to do that is *global*, i.e. calling `.addEventListener` on a global object like `window` or `document` going to have to be done that way. Global concerns sit *outside* the React model, and it's up to you to hook it into React using the lifecycle methods or `useEffect`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lift the state up to a parent component. Pass the selected state down to each child component. Use an effect hook to wire up a global event handler to catch clicks elsewhere in the document.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null);
  console.log(selected);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const clearSelected = () => setSelected(null);
    window.addEventListener("click", clearSelected);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", clearSelected);
  }, []);

  const values = ["a", "b", "c"];

  return (
    <div>
      {values.map((value) => (
        <Child
          key={value}
          value={value}
          selected={value === selected}
          setSelected={setSelected}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ value, selected, setSelected }) => {
  console.log({ setSelected, selected, value });
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={selected ? "selected" : "not-selected"}
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        setSelected(value);
      }}
    >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Also will I run into any issue if I use event listeners in useeffect?

Comment: Only if you don't clean them up afterwards. Or if you try to bind them to things that get modified by React.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you call `setState` separately for each `NavItem`, and you don't have the common parent component to share that state, so you should lift your states to the parent component

I assume that you have a parent component called `Nav`

```
import React from 'react'
import NavItem from './NavItem'

function Nav() {
    const menu = {
        initial: "noborder",
        final: "border",
      };
    const [activeNavItem, setActiveNavItem] = useState(1); //active the first `NavItem`
    //you can reduce duplication by `map` or depends on your setup
    return <>
       <NavItem itemStyle={activeNavItem === 1 ? menu.final : menu.initial } handleClick={() => setActiveNavItem(1)}>Item 1</NavItem>
       <NavItem itemStyle={activeNavItem === 2 ? menu.final : menu.initial } handleClick={() => setActiveNavItem(2)}>Item 2</NavItem>
       <NavItem itemStyle={activeNavItem === 3 ? menu.final : menu.initial } handleClick={() => setActiveNavItem(3)}>Item 3</NavItem>
    </>
}

export default Nav
```

Now you have the same state for all `NavItem`

```
import React from 'react'

function NavItem({ itemStyle, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick} className={`${itemStyle}`}>NavItem</div>
  )
}

export default NavItem
```